# Where can I get this "MVC" class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I have noticed quite a few posts on web where people use some class named MVC to get controllers and actions.

```
MVC.Home.Index().GetRouteValueDictionary()
```

Where does it come from? I cannot find this class anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/), I believe.